# Problem using analytics:reportChart in Force.com site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, report-chart

I've created a VF page to display a standart chart. The page is working fine from within SF. When trying to open the page from Force.com site I get the following error:

> Error while running $A.run() : Unknown component:
>   markup://aura:component

Any ideas?

The VF page is:

```
<apex:page > 
   <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oxxxxxx"></analytics:reportChart>     
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use that component on a public site page because the guest user cannot have the Run Reports permission.  You will have to create the chart on your own.  Use something like the google charts or D3 libraries to help